# Running cmd in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, directory, project

Is there any difference between:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\foldername";
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
startInfo.FileName = path + @"\do_run.cmd";
startInfo.Arguments = "/c arg1 arg2";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

and

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\foldername";
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c cd " + path + " && do_run arg1 arg2";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

For some reason, the second block of code is working correctly but the first block is not.

Secondly, I can't use my `C:` directory when releasing the application, so how do I run `cmd.exe` within the Visual Studio project folder?

Thanks

Comment: Simply use `cmd.exe` - [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) includes the System32 folder.

Comment: My concern was that the path would be different if the application ran on a different machine? I plan on running this on a virtual machine running windows, should your solution still work?

Comment: As I stated before: PATH includes the System32 folder (where cmd.exe resides).

Comment: In addition to John, you can use `%windir%\System32\cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `cmd.exe`:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\foldername";
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/c cd " + path + " && do_run arg1 arg2";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Windows will, by default, include System32 (where `cmd.exe` resides) in the system [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable (meaning you can run `cmd.exe` from anywhere and it will find it).

As to why your first code doesn't work, I'm not 100% sure, but if you're running on .NET Core you might need to set `UseShellExecute` to `true` since, unlike .NET Framework, it defaults to `false`. That said, I'd argue the above is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

... 

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

// We want a standard path (special folder) which is C:\windows\system32 in your case
// Path.Combine - let .Net make paths for you 
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 
 "cmd.exe");

string path = Path.Combine(
  // If you want exe path; change into 
  //   Environment.CurrentDirectory if you want current directory
  // if you want current directory
  Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), 
 @"foldername");

// ""{path}"" - be careful since path can contain space(s)
startInfo.Arguments = $@"/c cd ""{path}"" && do_run arg1 arg2";

// using : do not forget to Dispose (i.e. free unmanaged resources - HProcess, HThread)
using (Process.Start(startInfo)) {
  ... 
}
```